# How to make title bar buttons in Ubuntu with Tkinter

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, button

I want to add a 'Run' Button at the right of the title bar of my Tkinter project. I see this feature is in Ubuntu but I couldn't find how to make this work.

My Tkinter window looks like this: [Tkinter window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWRp2.png)

Here's and image of how a window with this kind of buttons looks like: [Default Text Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilhcg.png)

I can also use other languages and libraries if I can't recreate this using Python or Tkinter

Comment: go through this [github repo](https://github.com/morten1982/crossviper/)

Comment: You can create a menu bar and d button there or you can learn how the default code editor in ubuntu is built [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit/blob/master/gedit/Gedit.py)